# select and display employess who have the same deptno and mgr as the prompted ename by the user

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, sqlplus

Display the employees  who have the same DEPTNO and MGR of a given employee(Prompt), excluding that  employee.
can anyone help me with this one and tell me how i exclude the employee that is given by the user.

```
select ename,deptno,mgr from emp where 
deptno=(select deptno from emp where ename='&&ename') 
AND 
mgr=(select mgr from emp where ename='&ename');
```

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately your question isn't very clear, as written. Please edit your question to explain what issue you're having. Currently it's just a query, and a general requirement. Please show some sample data, sample output expected, actual output (or errors) you're getting, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
SQL> select deptno, empno, ename, mgr
  2  from emp
  3  order by deptno, mgr;

    DEPTNO      EMPNO ENAME             MGR
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        10       7934 MILLER           7782
        10       7782 CLARK            7839
        10       7839 KING
        20       7788 SCOTT            7566
        20       7902 FORD             7566
        20       7876 ADAMS            7788
        20       7566 JONES            7839
        20       7369 SMITH            7902
        30       7521 WARD             7698  --> we'll watch these
        30       7499 ALLEN            7698  -->
        30       7844 TURNER           7698  -->
        30       7900 JAMES            7698  -->
        30       7654 MARTIN           7698  --> employees
        30       7698 BLAKE            7839

14 rows selected.
```

Query: lines #3 - 6 select those with the same `DEPTNO` and `MGR`, while line #7 excludes that very employee (identified by `PAR_EMPNO`).

```
SQL> select e.*
  2  from emp e
  3  where (e.deptno, e.mgr) = (select a.deptno, a.mgr
  4                             from emp a
  5                             where a.empno = &&par_empno
  6                            )
  7    and e.empno <> &&par_empno;
Enter value for par_empno: 7521

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE          SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 02/20/1981       1600        300         30
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 09/28/1981       1250       1400         30
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 09/08/1981       1500          0         30
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 12/03/1981        950                    30

SQL>
```